# Как реализовать функцию вывода двумерного вектора на экран и в файл?

Tags: c++, вектор

В программировании на C++ столкнулся с особенностью выделения\освобождения памяти при создании динамических массивов, и чтобы не запутаться решил использовать `std::vector`. Нагуглил инфы о том, какие методы там есть, но не смог найти путной инфы о работе с дву/трёхмерными векторами (не силён в ООП). Может вдогонку кто-нибудь объяснит общую логику работы с двухмерными векторами в принципе?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

     vector <vector<int> > v; // создаем вектор векторов 
     int n;

     cin >> n;

     v.resize(n+1); // после resize в векторе появилось n пустых векторов, в которые ты можешь push_back-кать
     // к ячейкам вектора можешь обращаться по такому циклу
     for(int i = 0; i < (int)v[i].size(); ++i)


     return 0;

}
```

Comment: Спасибо!
Попробую разобраться. 
А если заранее не известно какой размерности вектор? (2-х, 3-х и т д, т е n-мерный? Не подскажете как выйти из ситуации?

Comment: @АндрейСамотаров каждый раз когда увеличиваем размерность вектора, делаем resize на сколько нам нужно

Comment: @Алексей Какой смысл приводить тип значения, возвращаемого функцией size()  к типу int? И зачем вызывать push_back если нужное количество элементов в векторе уже установлено с помощью функции resize?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Лично у меня компилятор ругается на это, говорит что разные типы, а вопрос с push_back не понял немного

Comment: @Алексей Правильно делает компилятор, что ругается, так как не понятно, почему используется тип Int. Что касается второго замечания, то зачем использовать метод push_back, когда вы уже с помощью resize уже выделили нужное количество элементов в векторе?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Он ругается без этой записи :) На счет второго замечания, после resize появилось n пустых векторов, как вы собираетесь его заполнять без push_back?

Comment: @Алексей, я имел в виду не количество вложенных векторов, а размерность в математическом понимании этого слова. Например для размерности три: вектор, в него вложен вектор и в этот вектор в свою очередь вложен вектор. Вот [ссылка](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/629961/Трёхмерный-stdveсtor) на другой мой вопрос, т к по вашему примеру не до конца разобрался что к чему. Буду рад на очень рад если подкинете ссылки где можно почитать про подобного рода манипуляции.

Comment: @Алексей компилятор ругается потому что  вы используете тип int там,, где его не следует использовать.  Что касается второго замечания, то не понятно, почему в одном случае используется resize а в другом случае push_back.

Comment: @VladfromMosсow еще раз повторюсь, если не поставить (int), вот что пишет компилятор: "warning: comparison signed ans unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare] ". Может вы знаете такой ресурс как e-maxx.ru, там так же ставят (int). Второе замечание, когда мы создали vector<vector> мы создали пустое множество, после resize, вектор приобрел количество строк i (как в массиве), но количество j элементов мы сами выбираем, тобишь делаем push_back.

Comment: @АндрейСамотаров , почитайте здесь, http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/