# Трёхмерный std::veсtor

Tags: c++, массивы, stl, динамические-массивы, вектор

По долгу службы пришлось иметь дело с трёхмерными векторами.
Подкиньте примерчик создания, и работы с трёхмерным вектором, в котором вложенные вектора произвольной длины.

- первый индекс задаёт количество векторов<векторов<<>>
- второй - количество ячеек в "первом"  вложенном векторе
- третий - количество ячеек конечного (вложенного "во второй") вектора.

В первую очередь хотелось бы понять, как обращаться к вложенным элементам. + весь этот вектор надо как-то передавать в функции не копируя, а напрямую, т.к. в таком виде удобно хранить (в контексте моей задачи) данные.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Так устроит?...

```
using vector3d = vector<vector<vector<int>>>;

// Передача по ссылке копирования не вызывает
void out(const vector3d& v)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < v[i].size(); ++j)
        {
            for(int k = 0; k < v[i][j].size(); ++k)
                cout << v[i][j][k] << " ";
            cout << endl;
        }
        cout << endl << endl << endl;
    }
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int n1 = 2, n2 = 3, n3 = 5;
    vector3d v(n1, vector<vector<int>>(n2, vector<int>(n3, 0)));

    for(int i = 0; i < n1; ++i)
    for(int j = 0; j < n2; ++j)
    for(int k = 0; k < n3; ++k)
        v[i][j][k] = (i+1)*100 + (j+1)*10 + k+1;

    out(v);

}
```

Тут есть и тип, и обращение, и передача в функцию. Сделал `int` для простоты.

Comment: Если не секрет, что именно не устроило заминусовавшего?...

Comment: Не знаю, минусовал не я.

Comment: Так я не к вам, а к заминусовавшему :) Обычно минус - значит явная ошибка, вот и спрашиваю - может, я что не заметил?...

Comment: Объявление вектора я поправил на такое: vector<vector<vector<int>>> vector3d; а вот передача по ссылке не получается: const vector3d& v - переменная vector3d не является именем типа. P.S. Пишу консольное на с++ P.P.S. Спасибо, что не обошли стороной.

Comment: `vector<vector<vector<int>>> vector3d;` - это объявление переменной, а у меня `vector3d` - **ТИП**. Естественно, что после вашего исправления компилятор ничего не понял... Вот полный работающий код: http://ideone.com/kyZygk

Comment: Не мешало бы добавить пару слов о том, почему этот код является ответом на вопрос.

Comment: @vp_arth И каких? По-моему, сам код является самодокументирующим :)

Comment: `самодокументированным`. Является, для тех, кто не задаёт вопросы, `как передавать в функции не копируя`