# Матрица как вектор векторов

Tags: c++, массивы

Вот тут - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/629964/228791 - в ответе использован тип трехмерной матрицы как вектора векторов векторов...

```
using vector3d = vector<vector<vector<int>>>;
```

Вообще-то более-менее понятно, но вопрос такой - ведь каждый вектор, например, в двумерной матрице, можно сделать своего размера? Если мы объявляем массив

```
double array[n][m];
```

то тут хоть в лепешку расшибись, но в каждой строке будет одинаковое число столбцов. А с векторами можно вектор удлиннить, скажем...

Вопрос такой - можно как-то средствами самого языка сделать так, чтоб матрица `vector<vector<double>>` имела фиксированные размеры? но при этом ее элементы можно было менять?

Под фиксированными размерами я имею в виду, чтоб все вектора внутри имели всегда один размер. Ну то есть есть у меня такая матрица `NxM`, я мог бы сделать, скажем, `Nx2M`, но чтоб не мог даже по ошибке как-то поменять у одних векторов размер на `2M`, у других на 3. Я пока придумал только свой класс-оболочку написать, но нельзя ли как-то без этого?

Comment: Ну так вам массивы нужны) Вектор он на то и вектор, чтобы менять можно было.

Comment: @vp_arth Сейчас, подправлю вопрос...

Answer (score 1):

Векторы - всего лишь динамические массивы. Представьте, что способ который вы ищете существует и вы его использовали.
Каким образом вы планируете добавить слой в вашу матрицу? Вам нужно пройтись циклом, и добавить нечто в каждый вектор. Посреди цикла ваша структура будет в неконсистентном состоянии.

---

Воспользуйтесь `std::array`:

```
array<array<array<int, l>, m>, n>
```

Или, по аналогии:

```
template <class T, size_t n, size_t m, size_t l>
using Matrix = array<array<array<int, l>, m>, n>;

Matrix<float, 3, 4, 5> matrix;
```

Вы можете сделать класс работы с такими матрицами, которые на любую мутацию возвращают новый экземпляр.

Comment: Да, но я неправильно поставил задачу, извините. Я имел в виду чтоб ну вот представьте, что у вас эти l,m,n можно по ходу работы менять - и матрица, и динамическая, и чтоб никак нельзя было случайно или специально неверно длины отдельных строк или столбцов поменять.

Comment: @Mikhailo ну тут уже вам не обойтись без написания своего класса с переопределением `operator[]`

Comment: @Flowneee Да, я же писал, что я придумал написать свой класс... но интересовался, нельзя ли этого добиться не написанием своенго класса, а стандартными средствами языка...

Answer (score 1):

Если вам нужен многомерный массив с натурально неизменными размерами подмассивов, то можно реализовать его так, как реализуются встроенные массивы языка, т.е. через одномерный массив с пересчетом индексов

```
std::vector<double> v(n * m * l);
```

с последующим доступом к элементу `[i][j][k]` как

```
v[i * m * l + j * l + k] // [(i * m + j) * l + k]
```

Готового класса, инкапсулирующего такой пересчет индексов я вам не назову, но при желании вы можете реализовать его самостоятельно.

Comment: Ну всё же https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/operator-overloading#matrix-subscript-op (и там как раз пример класса)

Comment: Да, я же писал, что я придумал написать свой класс... но интересовался, нельзя ли этого добиться не написанием своенго класса, а стандартными средствами языка...