# Какой тип аргумента указывать в конструкторе матрицы списком инициализации?

Tags: c++

Пишу шаблон класса матрицы со следующими приватными членами:

```
private:
    std::vector<std::vector<Type>> matr;
    std::pair<size_t, size_t> sizes_pair;
```

Хочу написать конструктор, который принимал бы список инициализации списков инициализации и им бы сразу инициализировался внутренний вектор векторов.

```
template<typename Type>
Matrix<Type>::Matrix(std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<Type>> list) :
    matr(list)
{
    sizes_pair(matr.size(), matr[0].size());
}
```

Но компилятор ругается на моменте инициализации matr, мол у вектора нет конструктора с такими типами аргументов, есть только с std::initializer_list.
Я могу конечно уже в теле конструктора присвоить matr нужные значения, но это долго , и хотелось бы сделать это на этапе инициализации. Как можно это сделать?

Comment: Maybe `std::initializer_list<std::vector<Type>>`?

Comment: @EOF Да, помогло. Нормально работает с подобным синтаксисом: {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}. Не могу отметить как верный ответ, т.к. комментарий

Comment: Лучше использовать "одномерный" вектор с [соответствующей индексацией](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/632172/398802); надо добавить `std::` для `std::size_t`